# The factor group $\mathbb{R} / \mathbb{Z}$ under addition has an infinite number of elements of order 4

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, quotient-group, infinite-groups

The factor group $\mathbb{R} / \mathbb{Z}$ under addition has an infinite number of elements of order 4.

The answer is false, but I cannot still understand it. I thought that it is true since there are infinite number of real numbers $x$ such that $4x \in \mathbb{Z}$. Why that this argument is incorrect?

Comment: Elements of $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ are not real numbers though, they are cosets. You got it right that such an element has to be of the form $\frac{m}{4}+\mathbb{Z}$ where $m\in\mathbb{Z}$. But are there infinitely many such distinct cosets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your argument is incorrect, because the problem is not about counting elements of $\mathbb R$.

It is instead about counting elements of $\mathbb R / \mathbb Z$. In other words, you should take the set
$$\{x \in \mathbb R \mid 4x \in \mathbb Z\}
$$
then you should subdivide it into cosets modulo $\mathbb Z$, and then you should count the number of cosets. That will be, *almost by definition*, the number of elements of the factor group $\mathbb R / \mathbb Z$ such that their order divides $4$ (then you'll have to winnow out the elements of order $2$ and $1$).

For example, the set $\frac{1}{4} + \mathbb Z = \{... \,-\frac{7}{4}, \, -\frac{3}{4}, \, \frac{1}{4}, \, \frac{5}{4}, \, \frac{9}{4} \,...\}$ consists of infinitely many real numbers $x$ such that $4x \in \mathbb Z$, but this set is just a single coset modulo $\mathbb Z$. It is just a single element of $\mathbb R / \mathbb Z$ of order dividing $4$, and in fact its order is exactly $4$ because $2 \cdot \frac{1}{4} \not\in \mathbb Z$ and $1 \cdot \frac{1}{4} \not\in \mathbb Z$.